# Изменить хранение в SESSION на хранение в COOKIES

Tags: php, joomla, cookie, сессия

Joomla 3.5.1
JoomShopping 4.14.1
Plugin & Module: Last visited products

В общем есть модуль:

```
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die;

if (!file_exists(JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_jshopping/jshopping.php')){
    JError::raiseError(500,"Please install component \"joomshopping\"");
} 

require_once JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_jshopping/lib/factory.php'; 
require_once JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_jshopping/lib/functions.php';        
JSFactory::loadCssFiles();
JSFactory::loadLanguageFile();
$jshopConfig = JSFactory::getConfig();
$session = JFactory::getSession();

$count = $params->get('count_products', 5);
$show_image = $params->get('show_image',1);
$show_name = $params->get('show_name',1);
$show_price = $params->get('show_price',1);
$show_manufacturer = $params->get('show_manufacturer',1);
$show_module = $params->get('show_module',1);

$products = array();
$last_visited_products = array_reverse($session->get('last_visited_products', array()));
$curent_product_id = JFactory::getApplication()->input->getInt('product_id');
foreach($last_visited_products as $product){
    if ($product->product_id == $curent_product_id) {
        continue;
    }
    $product->product_price = $product->orig_product_price;
    $product->image = $product->orig_image;
    if (count($products) noimage)) {
    $noimage = $jshopConfig->noimage;
} else {
    $noimage = 'noimage.gif';
}

require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath($module->module, $params->get('layout', 'default'));
```

И плагин:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

class plgJshoppingproductsJshopping_last_visit_product extends JPlugin {

    function onBeforeDisplayProductView($view) {
        $session = JFactory::getSession();
        $last_visited_products = $session->get('last_visited_products', array());
        if (isset($last_visited_products[$view->product->product_id])) {
            unset($last_visited_products[$view->product->product_id]);
        }
        $product = new stdClass();
        $product->name = $view->product->name;
        $product->orig_image = $view->product->image;
        $product->image = $view->product->image;
        $product->product_thumb_image = $view->product->product_thumb_image;
        $product->product_id = $view->product->product_id;
        $product->currency_id = $view->product->currency_id;
        $product->tax_id = $view->product->product_tax_id;
        $product->orig_product_price = $view->product->product_price;
        $product->product_price = $view->product->product_price;
        $product->product_old_price = $view->product->product_old_price;
        $product->min_price = $view->product->min_price;
        $product->different_prices = $view->product->different_prices;
        $product->product_manufacturer_id = $view->product->product_manufacturer_id;
        $product->vendor_id = $view->product->vendor_id;
        $product->delivery_times_id = $view->product->delivery_times_id;
        $product->label_id = $view->product->label_id;
        $product->category_id = $view->category_id;
        $last_visited_products[$product->product_id] = $product;
        $session->set('last_visited_products', $last_visited_products);
    }

}
```

Оба они хранят информацию о последних просмотренных продуктах в **SESSION**. Нужно изменить способ хранения информации на **COOKIE**.
Есть предложения как это реализовать??

Comment: Думаю, не выйдет. Размер кук ограничен, а вы храните в сессии массив продуктов со временем посещения каждого. Чем больше продуктов посещает пользователь, тем больше массив. И в некоторый момент произойдет ошибка переполнения.

Comment: @Visman хранить нужно несколько товаров а не все, например 3-5. Хранить в куках (на мой неопытный взгляд) нужно только product_id, а уже по нему определять все остальные переменные. **Плюс** есть подобные платные решения, значит всё возможно!!!

Comment: Больше ни одного предположения? Или вопрос как-то неправильно поставлен. Хоть какая-то бы реакция была...